# Place a LabelView dynamically under another LabelView

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have two `LabelViews`. The text added to the views is of variable size. how can I put the second `LabelView` immediately below the first `LabelView` without knowing the height of it?

How can I get the height of the first `LabelView` if it is set as 'automatic' to fit the text?

PS: I'm not using Alloy.

Comment: Lableview is a TextView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, @Manuel_Rodrigues I don't understand clear of your problem! If you have this problem in **Titanium**, the follow suggestion may help you. First, the **LabelViews** you said is the UI component of **Label** or **View**? And, according your descriptions I'm wonder are you want to do something like ***CHAT IN TEXT*** that the follow content of the chat under the last people chat content. If this is what you want, then:

1.Make the text auto fit the label

```
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    font:{
        fontSize: '18'                          //text font size
    },
    top: 10,                                    //the distance between the labels
    width: 'auto',                              //automatic define width by the text
    height: 'auto',                             //automatic define height by the text
    textAlign: 'center',                        //text display in the center of the label in horizontal direction
    verticalAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER  //text display in the center of the label in vertical direction
});
```

please **note** this:

If you set the **width** and **height** both with value **auto**, when the text is very long that the mobile screen can't display all the content, the label will not make a new line to display the rest text. So, the better way is set a specified value to the width or equal to the width of the mobile screen.

2.The next label display under the last label automatically

If you choose the **View** as the parent of these lables, you should set the property **layout** with value **vertical**. Well, if there's only **window** you defined, do the same thing.

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto',
    layout: 'vertical'
});
view.add(label1);
view.add(label2);
...
```

or for **window**:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    layout: 'vertical'
});
win.add(label1);
win.add(label2);
...
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: my error. they are labels and not lebelview. it works but can you tel my how can i put view's inside view's using the main view with a vertical layout?

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues  Yes, you can do that absolutely! Cause the UI component **view** can be put in another view, just like the _**div**_ in **html**. However, this is a particular case in Titanium, so you must have to know the level of the UI components completely. Just pay attention to it's **[API](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI)** , good luck!